# Stuck in a login loop after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, 18.04

I decided to try out Ubuntu 18.04 and upgrade it by following the steps found here[17.10 to 18.04](https://itsfoss.com//upgrade-ubuntu-version/), however I'm unable to login. I've tried the majority of the older solutions and none of them seems to work.

So far I tried:

1. Reinstalling lightdm
2. Starting and stopping the lightdm service
3. Adding a new user still loops
4. Reconfigure lightdm
5. Using chown on the Xauthority file.

Comment: This is not very descriptive. Edit your question with more details like , what were you doing , how problem arose, what have you tried to solve it so far. Links to resources you have read , etc

Comment: @anjanik012 okay done.

Comment: do you have nvidia or radeon  gpu?

Comment: @anjanik012 a Radeon.

Comment: were radeon graphics drivers installed when you did upgrade?

Comment: No. Just used the commands found on the website up to the point where it said to reboot.

Comment: Why are you messing with lightdm in numbered list elements 1. 2. and 4. ? gdm3 has replaced lightdm as the default login display manager in Ubuntu 18.04. gdm3 is the default login display manager in 18.04 whether it was upgraded from an earlier release or fresh installed.

Comment: I actually tried selecting gdm3 and when I do, I don’t even make it to the login screen.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using LightDM in 18.04 if gdm3 doesn't work, however it does make booting a little more complicated and that's why your question isn't a duplicate of anything.